# Nginx websocket proxy uses three connections per socket

Tags: sockets, nginx, proxy

I am trying to create an Nginx configuration that will serve as a proxy to incoming websocket connections (mainly for SSL offloading), but I am running into connection limits. I followed several guides and SO answers to accommodate more connections but something weird caught my attention. I currently have 18K clients connected and when I run `ss -s` on the Nginx machine, this is the report:

```
Total: 54417 (kernel 54537)
TCP:   54282 (estab 54000, closed 280, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 158/0), ports 18263

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         54537     -         -
RAW       0         0         0
UDP       1         1         0
TCP       54002     36001     18001
INET      54003     36002     18001
FRAG      0         0         0
```

I understand how there can be 36K IP connections, but what I do not get is where those additional IPv6 connections come from. I am having problems scaling above 25K connections and I think part of that comes from the fact that somehow there are three connections set up for each socket. So, my question is this: **does anyone know where those extra connections are coming from?**

The entire system is running within a Kubernetes cluster, with the configuration as follows:

`nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 500000;

error_log  /dev/stdout warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Increase worker connections to accommodate more sockets
events {
  worker_connections  500000;
  use epoll;
  multi_accept on;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  off; # don't use it, so don't waste cpu, i/o and other resources.

  tcp_nopush     on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

`proxy.conf` (included via conf.d):

```
  server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl backlog=100000;

    # Set a big keepalive timeout to make sure no connections are dropped by nginx
    # This should never be less than the MAX_CLIENT_PING_INTERVAL + MAX_CLIENT_PING_TIMEOUT in the ws-server config!
    keepalive_timeout 200s;
    keepalive_requests 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 200s;

    ssl_certificate           /app/secrets/cert.chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /app/secrets/key.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    location / {
      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8443;
      proxy_http_version  1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }
```

I also set the following options in Unix:

`/etc/sysctl.d/custom.conf`:

```
fs.file-max = 1000000
fs.nr_open = 1000000
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1048576
net.core.somaxconn = 1048576
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1048576
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range 1024 65000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 3240000
net.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse= 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout= 15
```

`/etc/security/limits.d/custom.conf`:

```
root soft nofile 1000000
root hard nofile 1000000
* soft nofile 1000000
* hard nofile 1000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of some colleagues I found out that this is actually Kubernetes confusing everything by joining containers within a Pod in one IP namespace (so that each container can access the other via `localhost` ([link](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/networking/))). So what I see there:

- Incoming connections from the proxy
- Outgoing connections from the proxy
- Incoming connections from the server

Although this does not help me to achieve more connections on a single instance, it does explain the weird behaviour.